# What are some high-calorie foods that are kosher for Passover?

Tags: product-recommendation, food, passover, health-safety-shmira

What are some high calorie foods that are kosher for Pesach? I have a diet that requires a lot of calories and am trying to prepare. I have [read](http://www.healthaliciousness.com/articles/highest-calorie-foods.php) that nut-wise, macadamia and pecans are high on the list. There is, of course, meat; but I can't have that for every meal. Aside from junk food, is there a category I'm missing? Any suggestions? (Please don't include kitniyos).

Comment: Can't you get all the same food groups as usual? 8 pieces of Matza Pizza ought to be full of calories.

Comment: cheeses and other dairy products? I like herring and cream sauce or cream cheese on matzah but theres also matzah brie with strawberry jelly. What high calorie foods do you eat the rest of the year?

Comment: Fish, cheese, and eggs come immediately to mind.

Comment: Potatoes, Olive oil (They can be combined to french fries).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of high fat kosher for Pesach foods. I included gebrochts options, but even without that there's still a lot.

Fleishiks: Dark chicken also has a fair amount of fat, especially the skin. You can get chicken wings, which have a high skin-to-meat ratio. Liver is high fat, as are gizzards (kurkeban, in Hebrew). If you're feeling adventurous, you can make shmaltz by boiling a large quantity of chicken skins. If you bake chicken, you can cook potatoes/other veggis in the gravy, or consume the high-fat gravy in some other way.

High Fat Dairy: Butter, sour cream, cream cheese, hard cheese, those spreadable "triangle" cheeses, cream.

Tuna in oil

Nuts, avocados

Kosher for Pesach salami, if you can find it, or other high fat cold cuts.
High fat hot dogs.

You can add oil/butter to the foods you eat to increase the fat content. You can use olive oil for the flavor and health benefits, but any kosher for Pesach oil will work.

Eggs - omelettes (fried in oil or butter), hard boiled eggs, egg salad (with mayo). The yolks are high fat.

All of these high fat foods would work well in/with salad. Add a high fat dressing (oil or mayo based) for extra calories.

Matzo balls!They have oil and eggs, plus matzo meal (and some water and salt).

You can make various high fat veggie kugels (add lots of oil and egg yolks), and put high-fat toppings on matza. You can add lots of butter or oil to mashed potatoes. Matza lasagna (made with sour cream, cheese, and spaghetti sauce) is another option.

I don't know what you usually drink, but you can avoid water and soda in favor of milk or fruit juice, which will add some relatively healthful calories. If you can find kosher for Pesach cream, you could drink that.

Man, I feel stuffed!

Chag Kasher Ve'Same'ach

-Rebbetzin HaQoton